# NodeJS streaming gzip to a file

Tags: node.js, zlib, createwritestream

I am trying to write gzip'd content to a file to make the file smaller.

I seem to be missing a step - when I read back the file, the text is plain text (e.g. `hello there`), instead of gzip'd content (e.g. `\u001f\ufffd\b\u0000\u0000\u0000...`).

I've written the following unit test to reproduce what I'm doing - hopefully someone can point out where I went wrong.

NodeJS: `v18.3.0`

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import zlib from 'zlib'

// ...

it('wip general - check compression to file works', async () => {
    // create gzip pipe to file
    const filename = path.join(tmpdir.name, 'test.txt.gz')
    const test = zlib.createGzip().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename, 'utf-8'))

    // write some content, wait for it to finish writing
    test.write('hello there', 'utf-8')
    test.end()
    await new Promise(resolve => test.on('finish', resolve))

    // check result is NOT plaintext
    expect(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')).not.eql('hello there')
})
```

Failure output:

> AssertionError: expected 'hello there' to not deeply equal 'hello there'

Answer (score 1):

Ok, worked it out.

When you call the `.pipe()` function, it returns the parameter you pass in... which means:

> `const test = zlib.createGzip().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))`

is actually setting `test` to the `createWriteStream`, completely bypassing the `gzip` stream.

The solution was to store the separate stream objects, to ensure we're writing to the `gzip` stream.

i.e.

```js
it('wip general - check compression to file works', async () => {
    const filename = path.join(tmpdir.name, 'test.txt')
    const out = fs.createWriteStream(filename, 'utf-8')
    const gzip = zlib.createGzip()
    gzip.pipe(out)
    gzip.write('hello there', 'utf-8')
    gzip.end()
    await new Promise(resolve => out.on('finish', resolve))

    // check result is encoded
    expect(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')).not.eql('hello there')
})
```