# How can I reverse a stream to read a JSONL backward?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I have a JSONL online file I need to parse line by line in the following format:

```
{ "id": "something1" }
{ "id": "foo1", "__parentId": "something1" }
{ "id": "something2" }
{ "id": "something3" }
{ "id": "foo2", "__parentId": "something3" }
{ "id": "something4" }
{ "id": "foo3", "__parentId": "something2" }
```

This file can be quite large (even 20GB). Currently I have the following code:

```js
await axios.get(url, { responseType: "stream" }).then(async (res) => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: res.data,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line) {
      await handleLine(JSON.parse(line));
    }
  }
});
```

This code works, but it will read the file from top to bottom, I need to parse it from bottom to top, because in this way once I process a parent I know all his children have already been processed.

I tried with saving it in a tmp file and read the file backward, this worked but as I said the file can potentially be infinite large, so I would like to find something to handle it directly with the nodejs streams, without saving it in my machine memory. I know streams are designed to be read sequentially from start to end, but is there a way to transform it, maybe with [TransformStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransformStream)?

Comment: Ignore node.js and the like for a moment - how do you think this could work on a basic computer level? Either you remember the unparsed representation of the parent (raw text), or you remember the parsed representation. "Save to temporary file" is the logical way to implement the first alternative.

Comment: Also, whitespace in JSON is mostly optional, including newlines. Your `JSON.parse(line)` makes little sense from a JSON perspective. `JSON.parse` is designed to parse an entire JSON object, not substrings from a larger JSON object.

Comment: @MSalters my `JSON.parse(line)` parse one line of my JSONL file, why do you think this makes little sense?

Comment: Oh - I got the impression that the example data was a fragment from a larger JSON object. But if it's indeed not nested (one complete object per line) then you can ignore my second comment. Still, you need to remember either the unparsed or the parsed representation. Streams are not seekable, you can't go back.

Comment: Since your stream is coming from HTTP, the only way I can see to read the data in reverse order is—if there is support for it server-side—to use [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) and parse the stream chunk by chunk. This requires you to know the size of the response in advance. — Would [gzipping the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495292) and [uncompressing while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075578) be a solution for the disk space concern?

Comment: @RickN thank you for the ideas. I do not hink the range request would be fine since I won't like to do multiple requests. I think that zipping the file may do the trick for now, care to write an answer?

Comment: Don't have time to go in depth; if you manage to do it by yourself, feel free to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).